# How to get element by ThymeLeaf dynamic Id in JavaScript jQuery.?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have used pre tag in my html like below. but I set its id using thymeleaf (don't sure if it is a correct way)

```
<pre th:id="'jsonViewer-' + ${obj.id}">[[${obj.payload}]]</pre>
```

so how to refer that element via javascript or jQuery. I've tried below way but not worked

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
   function formatJson() {
       var element = $("'#jsonViewer-' + ${obj.id}");//this one required to fix
       var obj = JSON.parse(element.text());
       element.html(JSON.stringify(obj, undefined, 2));
   }
   formatJson();
});
</script>
```

Comment: Hi, if there only one pre tag which you need to refer then you can use `$("pre[id*=jsonViewer-]")` this will select the pre tag which has `jsonViewer-` in the id and can end with anything.

Comment: See the [JavaScript inlining](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf#javascript-inlining) documentation - for example: `var id = /*[[${obj.id}]]*/ "-1";` or something similar.